# Querying my db, no error message, no data actually entered

Tags: php, sql

So I'm working on a zork like game for a school project, but I'm having some trouble with my SQL. I'm trying to insert a row of data for a new user so that when a user saves the game later on i can just update the row in the game progress table. My line of code, however, has a problem I haven't managed to solve. 
When I try to query the information into the database, it proceeds to the next script, no `or DIE` error messages, and no additional row of information in my db. Can anyone spot the issue? Bellow is my query and an image of my db before and after attempting the query. The one row of data was entered manually through sql.

[image]

```
//query to add user info to game_progress
$progress = "INSERT INTO `game_progress` [(`users_id`, `game_location`, `stealth`, `stool`, `item_in_hand`, `key_acquired`, `mom_door_unlocked`, `teddy_bear`, `cat_asleep`, `dog_asleep`, `chair`, `paper`, `game_won`)] VALUES ('$id', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null')";
mysqli_query ($dbc, $progress) or DIE ('Game progress was not inserted');
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly by identing by four spaces or using the shortcut `Ctrl + K`.

Comment: Why you're using `[]` in your code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, why you're using square brackets `[]` with your columns names `(users_id,game_location,stealth,stool,item_in_hand,key_acquired,mom_door_unlocked,teddy_bear,cat_asleep,dog_asleep,chair,paper,game_won)` can you try this code and check it now

```
//query to add user info to game_progress
$progress = "INSERT INTO game_progress (users_id, game_location, stealth, stool, item_in_hand, key_acquired, mom_door_unlocked, teddy_bear, cat_asleep, dog_asleep, chair, paper, game_won) VALUES ('$id', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null')";
mysqli_query ($dbc, $progress) or DIE ('Game progress was not inserted');
```

Answer (score 0):

(1) The square brackets (`[]`) in sql statement are not permitted.

(2) Don't insert `'null'` values like you do. Instead, ensure that in the db table each column have a default value assigned and/or accepts `NULL` as value.

(3) Use `mysqli_error()` functions in order to have the arised errors displayed. But be aware that these functions are used only on the development process, not on production. So, to test if a code works, they are good, but when you provide the code to the actual users, don't use them. Or use them to log the arised errors, not to display them to users.

That said, I simplified the code (you don't need that `null` values to test - see (2)) and implemented the `mysqli_error()` functions to help you to discover the problems yourself:

```
//query to add user info to game_progress
$progress = "INSERT INTO game_progress(users_id) VALUES ('$id')";
$inserted = mysqli_query($dbc, $progress);
if (!$inserted) {
    die('Game progress was not inserted. Error: ' . mysqli_errno($dbc) . ' - ' . mysqli_error($dbc) . ' - ' . mysqli_error_list($dbc) . ' - ' . mysqli_warning_count($dbc));
}
```

Good luck!